# JQuery Menu bar unnecessary repetition of animation

Tags: jquery, html, scroll, fadein, menubar

I have written a little jquery script to fadeout menus (called menew and menew2) on my website. When the user is at the top of the page, both are present. When the user is at the bottom, only the second (bottom bar) menu is present. When the user is halfway down the page, there are no menus.

```
/*Menu*/

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()<50){
            $('#menew').fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            $('#menew').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    }); 
});

/*Menu 2*/

$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop() > 0 - 50 + ($(document).height() - $(window).height())){
            $('#menew2').fadeIn("slow");
        } else if($(window).scrollTop()<50){
            $('#menew2').fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            $('#menew2').fadeOut("slow");
        }
    });
});
```

This works great, except that if I scroll from the bottom to the top, or vice versa quickly, the bottom menu (the only one present at both top and bottom of page) will continue to fully fadeout, before it can start to fade back in.

How can I recode this so that the menu will stop fading out and will start fading back in when it reaches the top/bottom.

An extension of the problem is that if the user goes mad scrolling (*EG they scroll down 50+px then back to the top several times in a row*), when they stop, the menus will carry on fading out and in until completing the number of cycles the user did. How can I add code to cancel the fade out/in once the user stop scrolling.

**Any help is appreciated :)**

Answer (score 0):

try .stop() before starting any animation 
http://api.jquery.com/stop/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if($(window).scrollTop()<50){
            $('#menew').stop().fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            $('#menew').stop().fadeOut("slow");
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Michael but this doesn't seem to help.
I also tryed changing each if/else to be like this:
  if(){
   $('#menew').stop();
   $('#menew').fadeIn("slow");
Unfortunately neither code fixes it. The stop does stop the menew, bu it also stops it from ever fading back in again.